# Are the field names localized in the file /var/lib/dpkg/status?

Tags: apt, dpkg, localization

Are the field names localized in the file /var/lib/dpkg/status?

I'm writing some code to parse the package names from the 'status' file. I need to know if the field names like "Package", "Status", etc are in English on non-English systems.

```
--Sample--

Package: libatk-adaptor
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 81
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: at-spi2-atk
Version: 2.14.0-2ubuntu1
Replaces: at-spi
Provides: at-spi
Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0 (>= 2.5.3), libc6 (>= 2.2.5), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0)
Conflicts: at-spi
Description: AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge
 This package includes a gtk-module that bridges ATK to the new
 D-Bus based AT-SPI.
Homepage: https://wiki.gnome.org/Accessibility
Original-Maintainer: Debian Accessibility Team <debian-accessibility@lists.debian.org>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are never localised but always in English.